# Jordan measure example

Tags: measure-theory

I was searching for examples to get a better understanding and I didn't find a lot. I found one but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly

Given $f:[0,1] \times [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as f(x,y) = xy. With $\int_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}fdx$ ( yes only dx).
To show that $A=[(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y| \leq 1 ]$ is Jordan measurable.

First they decompose it into the union of small boxes:
$$Q_{ij}=[\frac{i-1}{n};\frac{i}{n}]\times[\frac{j-1}{n};\frac{j}{n}]$$
Then the Riemann Integral is calculated = 1/4

2nd: We compute the integral of the characteristic function of the set A (proving that the
characteristic function is integrable is equivalent to showing that A is measurable). Due to symmetry, it is enough to show that the subset $A_1$ = {$(x, y) \in A : x, y > 0$}
is measurable; then we have $\mu(A) = 4*\mu(A_1)$.

3rd: Now we show that A1 is integrable by using Q.

$$\overline{S}(T_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i+2}=1/n^2*\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n-i+2)=1/n^2*\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i=\frac{1}{n^2}*[\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-1]$$
$$\underline{S}(T_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n*(n-1)}{2n^2}$$

Both have the limit 1/2.
Here we used the fact that $Q_{ij}\cap A_1= \emptyset$ if and only if j>n+2-i in the computation of the upper sum.
Hence $\mu(A_1)=1/2$, so A is also Jordan measurable and $\mu(A) = 4*\mu(A_1)=2$

My questions:

In the 2nd step, why is $\mu(A)=4\mu(A_1)$? 
Where did they define the characteristic function? Do I see it correctly that they force the upper limit out of bound with the index?

3rd step: Why are the indices chosen like they are? Why does j>n+2-i hold?
Further I don't understand how this shift is made from the double sum, to the the single sum in both cases.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What has the function $f$ to do with your question(s)?

Comment: I don't know. I just posted the full procedure